# DataTable Filtering Issue

Tags: jquery, datatable, filtering

I am using the datatable plug-in for jQuery. I am following this [link's](https://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/default.html) method which is used by many;however, I am not getting a textbox for searching each column instead, I am getting a normal text additional column and the original search textbox on the top-right along with the show entries dropbox are disappearing. Any idea why this is happening?

Any help is appreciated.

**Update (Code)**

```
<table id="g_table" class="table table-responsive table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.date_time) (mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.value_level)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.alert_status)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {           
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.date_time)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.value_level)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.alert_status)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Date and Time</th>
            <th>Level</th>
            <th>Alert Status</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Highcharts-4.0.1/js/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#g_table").dataTable().columnFilter();
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Need to see your code and what version of jQuery / DataTables you are using

Answer (score 0):

If you check your browser developer tools you'll probably see that plugin isn't defined.

You need to include the plugin provided by that site http://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/media/js/jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js.

Alternately, use more updated Data Tables and the method provided here https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html